# Creating tags expectations

Tags: support

I found a tag called "r". I don't know what it's used for. Can we all make a description for the tags that you created? That way we can use it properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, we should *not* create descriptions for tags like [r](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r).  This was a typo tag created when a user typed "gramma r" instead of "grammar".  I removed it from the question and retagged it.  It has no tag wiki, so it'll be automatically removed by the system shortly.  If it had a tag wiki, it would be needlessly kept around.